# Custom Javascript Validation without using map,filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, ecmascript-5

I have function for validation for check below scenarios, but function used map and filter methods. so `its not working in IE8`.How to rewrite this function without using map and filter.

```
var case1 = "stack(2),flow(2),over(4),temp(7)"; - true
var case2 = "stack(2),flow(3),over(4),temp(k)"; - false
var case3 = "stack(2),flow(2),over(4),temp(0"; - false
var case4 = "stack(2),flow(2),over(,temp)"; - false
var case5 = "stack(2),flow(2),over(4)temp(8)"; - false
var case6 = "stack(1),flow(7),over,temp"; - true
var case7 = "stack(1),flow(7),OVER,Temp"; - true
var case8 = "stack(1),flow(7),over_r,temp_t"; - true
```

Javascript function :

```
function validateChunk(s)
{
    return !!s.match(/^[a-z]+(?:\(\d+\))?$/);
}

function filterValid(v)
{
    return !v;
}

function testCases(str)
{
    var chunks = str.split(",");
    var validated = chunks.map(validateChunk);
    return (0 === validated.filter(filterValid).length);

}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8t26/7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach is to call validateChunk function in a loop:

```
for (var i = 0, l = chunks.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (! validateChunk(chunks[i])) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

As a sidenote, there's exactly zero sense to use `.match` when `.test` clearly suffices (as you don't have to collect the results of match). So I'd rewrite the function like this:

```
function validateChunk(str) {
  return /^[a-z]+(?:\(\d+\))?$/.test(str);
}
```

Finally, can't help noticing that all this validation can be done with a single regex:

```
function testCases(str)
{
    var pattern = /^[a-z]+(?:\(\d+\))?(?:,[a-z]+(?:\(\d+\))?)*$/
    return pattern.test(str);
}
```

Actually, judging from your description, the pattern should be slightly different: first, `_` symbol is valid one and should be included to character class; second, the same class should either include `A-Z` range as well, or instead a pattern should be given `/i` modififer. [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zm375/) includes all these changes.

Comment: +1 Actually your for loop seems to be a better solution than the original.

Comment: Great , Its works well. As well thanks for simplified the method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use polyfills for these methods - these will make them work even in browsers that don't support them. I simply copied the polyfills from MDN.

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) polyfill:

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
  Array.prototype.map = function(fun /*, thisArg */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array(len);
    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      // NOTE: Absolute correctness would demand Object.defineProperty
      //       be used.  But this method is fairly new, and failure is
      //       possible only if Object.prototype or Array.prototype
      //       has a property |i| (very unlikely), so use a less-correct
      //       but more portable alternative.
      if (i in t)
        res[i] = fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t);
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) polyfill:

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisArg */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
      {
        var val = t[i];

        // NOTE: Technically this should Object.defineProperty at
        //       the next index, as push can be affected by
        //       properties on Object.prototype and Array.prototype.
        //       But that method's new, and collisions should be
        //       rare, so use the more-compatible alternative.
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```